# How do I construct a struct in a union?

Tags: c++, unions

t2 below causes the following compile error

```
test.cpp:14:15: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'E' with an rvalue of type 'int'
        Test t2{2, {{2, 3}}};
                    ^
test.cpp:14:18: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'void *' with an rvalue of type 'int'
        Test t2{2, {{2, 3}}};
```

How do I initialize the second set? Would it be possible if I switch the struct and union around?

```
enum E {
    ea, eb, ec
};
struct Test {
    int a;
    union {
        struct{E e; void*p; };
        struct{int b, c; };
    };
};

int main() {
    Test t1{1, {{ea, 0}}};
    Test t2{2, {{2, 3}}};
}
```

Comment: C++ and unions are quite complicated to implement correctly. With C++17, `std::variant` is the solution you want.

Comment: I don't think anonymous structs are kosher in C++. Could be some weird behaviour there, but assuming GCC, you'll probably get C-like behaviour.

Comment: `Test t2{2, {{2, 3}}};` converts an `int` to an `enum` and an `int` to a pointer. Both not legal without a cast.. That has nothing to do with the uniion.

Comment: @user4581301 C++ forces you to typecast ints to enums so only the second set is compatible. Also ints aren't casted into void* automatically either

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @user4581301 it hit me 15mins later thats what you meant but I wasn't sure what you're trying to say if you were agreeing that it isn't ambiguous. By then I was having dinner and completely forgot to clarify anything/delete my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, only the first (non-static) member of the `union` can be initialized in this way.  Read more:

http://www.hellenico.gr/cpp/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization.html

Comment: Link looks to e a scrape of cppreference. Here's the direct link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Side note: If C++20 is available you can use designated initializers. But not with anonymous structs. With anonymous structs in play I can't guarantee this otherwise correct answer is correct. Such is the pain of non-Standard extensions.